# Mark inserted AutoText with bookmark VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I want to insert AutoText (with styles and colours) in the document en mark this range as a bookmark with Word VBA.
I know how to do this with normal text, but I can't figure out how to mark the inserted Autotext.
Help would be very welcome and appreciated.

Kind regards,
Kem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert AutoText, it returns a Range object representing the inserted AutoText. Assuming `doc` is your Document and you want to insert the AutoText item at the Selection:

```
' add AutoText item
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = doc.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries.Item("MyAutoTextItem").Insert(Selection.Range, True)

' set it to be a Bookmark
Dim bkmk As Bookmark
Set bkmk = doc.Bookmarks.Add("MyBookmark", rng)
```

... obviously adjust "MyAutoTextItem" and "MyBookmark" for your requirements

Comment: Hi John,
Yes. Just what I was looking for. This works great. Thank you so much.
Kem